# Can't access docker application from localhost using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

before I start: I have searched this question already and implemented what the "Solutions" were and it did not help (setting host to 0.0.0.0). So, with that out of the way,

Directory structure

```
|-- osr
|    |-- __init__.py
|-- requirements.txt
|-- Dockerfile
|-- docker-compose.yml
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.5-buster

EXPOSE 5000 # i have tried with and without this

ENV INSTALL_PATH /osr
ENV FLASK_APP osr
ENV FLASK_ENV development
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - '5000:5000'
        expose:
            - '5000'
        volumes:
            - .:/osr
```

__ init __.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev'
    )

    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'

    return app
```

docker-compose build web
docker-compose run web

```
 * Serving Flask app "osr" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 225-441-434
```

all of the below return "hmm can't reach this page"

```
http://localhost
http://localhost:5000/hello
http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello
```

I've even tried going to the containers IP with

docker exec -it 49e677 bash
ip add | grep global
    inet 172.21.0.2/16 brd 172.21.255.255 scope global eth0

```
http://127.21.0.2:5000/hello # nothing
```

Nothing.

I'm sure the app itself works fine as I can simply run the app directly.

```
$env:FLASK_APP="osr"
$env:FLASK_ENV="development"
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

And it runs fine

[image: localhost]

**EDIT: UPDATE**

I am actually able to get to the container when I run it through simply the Dockerfile... using

docker run -it -p 5000:5000 osr_web # the container built by docker-compose build

With this, I am able to access the endpoint through localhost:5000/hello

So the issue appears to lie in spinning it up through docker-compose run

Does this help at all?

**UPDATE 2**

I have discovered that when I run docker ps -a I can see that Docker run actually exposes the port, but docker-compose run does not:

[image]

Comment: What's your host OS?  (Is it more specifically an older Windows where you need Docker Toolbox?)  Do you have a firewall setup that might need to be adjusted?

Comment: I am using the most up to date Windows 10, does Windows 10 need to allow firewall for outbound in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure app works fine itself? I tried to run your python `__init__.py` file and ended up with an error.

```
python osr/__init__.py 
  File "osr/__init__.py", line 11
    def hello():
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

It works after fixing the indentation error.

```
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

$ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 harik8/osr:latest 
76628f86fecb61c0be4a969d3c91c5c575702ad8063b594a6c1c90b498ea25f1

$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello
Hello, World!
```

You can't run both docker and docker-compose in port 5000 at the same time. Either run one at a time or change the docker-compose/dockerfile host port.

```
$ docker ps -a | grep osr
8b885c4a9654        harik8/osr:latest                                     "flask run --host=0.…"   12 seconds ago       Up 11 seconds               0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp
$ docker ps -a | grep q5      
70f38bf11e26        q5_web                                                "flask run --host=0.…"   About a minute ago   Up 10 seconds               0.0.0.0:5001->5000/tcp
```

---

```
$ docker ps -a | grep q5
f9f6ba999109        q5_web                                                "flask run --host=0.…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp                                                                                                   q5_web_1
$ docker ps -a | grep osr
93fb421333e4        harik8/osr:latest                                     "flask run --host=0.…"   18 seconds ago      Up 18 seconds               5000/tcp
```

Comment: It was mis-pasted, the tabbing didn't copy over and I had to do it manually, the code is already as you posted, sorry I'll fix it in the question

Comment: Also, please note the update in the question. This works with docker run as you have shown, but not docker-compose run for some reason.

Comment: There is no error, I simply can't connect to the endpoint. I posted all the relevant information. It gives no error and starts up as expected. Please review the question.

Comment: As you can see the first was run with -it . Therefore simply exiting the container stopped it. Changing the port still does nothing and the port is not exposed. Are you using docker-compose in your tests? If not you are not simulating the environment.

Comment: @Aserian Flag `it` opens a tty session and it keeps the container alive. I was able to simulate the scenario and I have updated the answer.

Comment: sorry but this is still not the answer, after fully shutting down and removing the containers then rebuilding with each method, it still couldn't access it. I did find out the issue though, I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. For reference, I am running these versions:

`docker-compose version 1.25.5, build 8a1c60f6`

`Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b`

There were a couple issues: First and foremost to get the ports exposed I needed to run one of two options.

`docker-compose up web` 
or
`docker-compose run --service-ports web`

Simply running `docker-compose run web` would not expose the ports.

Once this was finished, I was able to access the endpoint. However I started getting another odd error,

```
flask.cli.NoAppException
flask.cli.NoAppException: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module  
"osr". Use "FLASK_APP=osr:name to specify one.
```

I had not experienced this simply using `docker run -it -p 5000:5000 osr_web` which was odd. However I noticed I had not set the work directory in the Dockerfile.

I changed the Dockerfile to this:

```
FROM python:3.7.5-buster

EXPOSE 5000
ENV INSTALL_PATH /osr
ENV FLASK_APP osr
ENV FLASK_ENV development
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# added this line
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY . .

CMD [ "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

I believe you could get away without setting the WORK_DIR if you turn the flask application into a package and install it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue, using docker compose with a target Dockerfile. I took the example from nextjs https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker-multi-env/docker/development

Everything was running correctly, and after some head banging, I noticed that there's a comment about not exposing ports in Dockerfile in their other example:

`# Note: Don't expose ports here, Compose will handle that for us`
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/0082d54893893b71b4be50b1ace748015781c0dc/examples/with-docker-compose/next-app/dev.Dockerfile#L24

I removed these lines from Dockerfile, rebuilt, and it's working now as expected.:

```
EXPOSE 3000
ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME localhost
```